# MultiValued string profile property limitation?

Tags: 2013, user-profile

When you create a user profile property of type string and that accepts multiple values, SharePoint seems to use a term set.

Actually, all values put in the users' profile appears in the keywords termset.

Does it means that values in the users' profile are limited to 30000 distinct values?

Worst, distinct values accross **all** profile properties?

I'm refering to the [technet Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013 page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#termstore)

Comment: I believe that would be the case, but there is nothing stopping you from defining what term set the field should belong to if you are worried about boundary limits.

Comment: But I understand correctly, for a single userprofileproperty, you can only have 30K distinct values, isn't it?

Comment: That is what the boundary says yes. You don't have to allow users to write to the field, you can use a predefined term set if that helps, not sure what you are trying to capture.